# Setting up the correct path for packages installed through pip (VS code, macos 14.2.1)

Tags: visual-studio-code, pip, path, package, zsh

I'm trying to run pip packages installed through "pip3 install " on VS code. The path for python 3 (default interpreter) is
`/usr/bin/python3`, and those packages are
`/Users/<user name>/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages`.

I do see the lists of packages installed through `pip3 list`, but I'm having issues with running those packages with the VS code terminal.  But when I try to run those packages, or even trying to get the version of each packages through `<package name> --version`, it gives me an error with "zsh: command not found" error.

How should I set the path correctly so the python interpreter gets access to those packages installed?

I've tried editing the json files by adding this line:
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": "PATH": "${env:PATH}"

This didn't seem to help.

I have python 3.9.6 and pip 23.3.2.

Comment: The names shown by `pip3 list` are *distribution packages* (DP), which are essentially the names of archive files that *contain* Python code. A given DP *might* install an script (and sometimes that script will have the same name as the DP), but in general the DP will provides modules that are meant to be *imported* from inside another module or script.